# Capture strings and pass it into an argument as a List<string>

Tags: c#, string, selenium, arraylist, c#-4.0

I have several strings inside try catches that uses the same variable *location*

```cs
try
{
    IWebElement bi7_reportHolder = ieDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("iframe-qlik-view"));
    //Check if Pop-up is present
    location = ssLocation["SaveScreenShotLocation"] + "bi7_ScreenShot.png";
    CheckPopUpAndTakeScreenShot(ieDriver, executor, location);
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}


//Open bi8 Report - Concentration Risk
ieDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://insightsmp.accenture.com/reports/9615a4f8-765f-4bed-9ccd-f8fa7cf3cbae/");
Thread.Sleep(60000);
wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
try
{
    IWebElement bi8_reportHolder = ieDriver.FindElement(By.Id("reportParent"));
    //Check if Pop-up is present
    location = ssLocation["SaveScreenShotLocation"] + "bi8_ScreenShot.png";
    CheckPopUpAndTakeScreenShot(ieDriver, executor, location);
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

//Open Detailed Reporting
ieDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://insightsmp.accenture.com/detailedReporting/");
Thread.Sleep(60000);
wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
try
{
    IWebElement dr_reportHolder = ieDriver.FindElement(By.Id("search-bar"));
    //Check if Pop-up is present
    location = ssLocation["SaveScreenShotLocation"] + "DR_ScreenShot.png";
    CheckPopUpAndTakeScreenShot(ieDriver, executor, location);
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

I need to capture all those strings and pass it as a List argument into a method that I'm calling so that I can use them in the method.

```cs
List<string> screenshotLocation = location.ToString();

SendEmail(Application, screenshotLocation, bi6Accessible, bi7Accessible, bi8Accessible, detailedReportingAccessible);
```

**How should I do this?**

Comment: You are almost there. Create a list, then [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netcore-3.1) the string to it. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above your first `try` statement, initialize your list.

```cs
List<string> screenshotLocation = new List<string>();
```

Then, each time you set the *location* variable, add it to that list, like so.

```cs
location = ssLocation["SaveScreenShotLocation"] + "bi7_ScreenShot.png";
screenshotLocation.Add(location);
//other code
```

Then when it comes tome to call your `SendEmail` method, the list is ready to go with the values added. you can call it like you have it. (Assuming the other variables are also correct)